# How do I use an arithmetic expression in the where clause of a SQL query that has a Group By clause without getting arithmetic overflow?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure

I have an Azure SQL DB and my query keeps throwing an arithmetic overflow error when it runs over too many rows. This is a sanitized version of my query (SET_END_TIME and SET_START_TIME are FLOAT type):

```
select t1.value1
from TABLE1 t1
    join TABLE2 t2
    on t1.ID = t2.ID
where
    (t1.SET_END_TIME - t1.SET_START_TIME) > 2
    and
    t2.CREATED_AT > '2017-06-11T00:00:00'
group BY
    t1.value1;
```

If I run this with another and in the where clause that restricts the date to two days, it runs fine. E.g. if I added

```
and t2.CREATED_AT < '2017-06-13T00:00:00'
```

So I know the issue is somehow related to the number of rows it is running over, but I don't understand why since the actual arithmetic operation should only be done row by row. Does anyone know what could be causing the overflow error and how I can fix my query to be able to run over many rows?

EDIT:
I know I have invalid values. I can see SET_START_TIME values of 1.79769313486232E+308 and -8.98846567431158E+307. Is there anyway I can tell the query to ignore invalid values (e.g. any Set start time > 100 and < 0) so it won't try to run the arithmetic on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the root cause was invalid values in the columns I was using for the arithmetic in my where clause, and the solution was to use a case expression inside a subquery to first sanitize the values I want to perform the arithmetic on, then filter on them in the outer query. Example:

```
select
    t1.value1,
    count(*) as total_values
from
    (
        select
            t1.ID as innerID,
            (case when t1.SET_START_TIME < 10000 and t1.SET_START_TIME > 0 then t1.SET_START_TIME else 0 end) as set_start,
            (case when t1.SET_END_TIME < 10000 and t1.SET_END_TIME > 0 then t1.SET_END_TIME else 0 end) as set_end
        from TABLE1 t1
    ) innerTable
    join TABLE2 t2
    on innerID = t2.ID
where
    (set_end - set_start) > 2
    and
    t2.CREATED_AT > '2017-06-11T00:00:00'
group by
    t1.value1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be suspicious of the values in SET_END_TIME and SET_START_TIME and that calculation causing you the error.  Can you output each column and see if perhaps SET_START_TIME is negative at some point and that produces the error you get?

Comment: I don't think it is the values though, since I can run the query over the same range and not get the error so long as it is a smaller range. E.g. Running it for June 11 - 13 and June 13 - 15 works, but running it from June 11 - 15 does not work.

Comment: You get more rows though, so more chance of error. It just takes one row with an unexpected value to cause that error.  Just run the select and take that part out of the where clause would be another way to troubleshoot/isolate the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If they are the exact same rows, just in one case they are being run over in two separate queries and in another they are being run over in a single query how would that cause the error? E.g. Say I have 6 rows, A,B,C,D,E,F. When I run June 11 - 13 it is running over A,B,C and when I run June 13 - 15 it is running over D, E, F, and both those queries work fine. Then I run June 11 - 15, it is running over A,B,C,D,E,F. So The exact same arithmetic operations are being performed, but when run over all 6 rows it fails.

Comment: Oh sorry misunderstood you.  That is puzzling.  It has to be that calc though right?  There is nothing else that would cause that error.  If it were me, I'd take it out of the where and put it in the select and see if it errors... I'm stretching now, not too sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the group by.

If you want distinct values for t1.value add the distinct keyword in the select.

(just thinking out loud)

Comment: I need the group by unfortunately, in the actual query this is a count() in there.